# How to adapt "normal" adjective?

Tags: грамматика

I am trying to learn the grammar and adjectives. I am not sure that I got it all right so please correct me if I am wrong. I think that there is a distinction between if the noun "has a heart beat" or not. If it is a thing then nominativ and ackusative cases are the same like in this example. What happens in ackusative case if the noun is of a kind (what do you call it in English/russian?) that forces acusative to change?

Adjective: чёрный
Noun: дом (Masculine)

Normal Adjectives - Hard (“-ый”, “-ой”, “-ий” (but not “-ний”))

Nominative Case: чёрный дом

Accusative Case: чёрный

Genitive Case: чёрного

Dative Case: чёрному

Instrumental Case: чёрным

Prepositional Case: чёрном

References:
http://www.russianlessons.net/grammar/adjectives.php

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9#Adjective

Comment: As you probably could have guessed (and I have pointed out this more than once that) I am new to this forum. If you correct me or give me a reference I will adapt. When you just have an opinion (no reference) then I do not reflection about it because everyone have opinions nowadays. Someone else had a similar comment as you did and I started to accept answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accusative case forms differ for ***animate*** versus ***inanimate*** objects.  *In the 2nd declension* the accusative or an ***animate*** noun coincides with the *genitive case*, and the accusative for an ***inanimate*** object coincides with the *nominative*.

> Nominative: ***Человек*** .  ***Дом***
>   Genitive: ***Человека*** .  ***Дома***
>   Accusative: ***Человека*** . ***Дом***

The adjectives change their form to match the noun they define.

You can find more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_declension), for instance.